# Mapping image onto JS cloth and creating a slider

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, canvas

Here is all the code for the website, it has many bugs, like the footer which is stuck in the middle. So the idea is to create 11 different tissues in the format of this image mapped to the JS I have, bit i dont know how to do that.[![sample tissue][1]][1]

I would like to create a slider that functions when you click on the collection number it switchees to the next collection.

Also all the links only take the  size and not the column width when hovered.

````
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>$</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="normalize.css">
  <style type="text/css">
    * {
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    -o-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
body {
}
#c {
    display: block;
    margin: 20px auto 0;
}
#info {
    position: absolute;
    left: -1px;
    top: -1px;
    width: auto;
    max-width: 420px;
    height: auto;
    background: #f8f8f8;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
}
#top {
    background: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
}
p {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #666;
    text-align: justify;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 0px 16px;
}
#github, #twitter {
  color:#3377ee;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration:none;
}
.center {
  text-align: center;
}
#net {
  text-align:center;
  white-space:nowrap;
  font-size:19px;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  padding:8px 12px;
  border-radius:8px;
  display:block;
  color:#888;
}
#net > span {
  color:#3377ee;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration:none;
}


.bull {
  opacity: 0.3;
  margin: 0 6px;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.column {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 800px) {
  .column {
    flex: 1;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 800px) {
  ._25 {
    flex: 2.5;
  }
  ._55 {
    flex: 5.5;
  }
  ._20 {
    flex: 2;
  }
}
 a:link {
  text-decoration: none;
}

 a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
background: black;}

 a:active {
  text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
background: black;
}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <a href="">Rakṣas Sari collection</a>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
   <a href=""> Concept</a>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
   <a href=""> Process</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
   <a href=""> Red Collection N°1</a>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
   <a href=""> Collection N°2</a>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
   <a href=""> Collection N°3</a>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
   <a href=""> Collection N°4</a>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
  <a href="">  Collection N°5</a>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
  <a href="">  Collection N°6</a>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
   <a href=""> Collection N°7</a>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
   <a href=""> Collection N°8</a>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
  <a href="">  Collection N°9</a>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
   <a href=""> Collection N°10</a>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
   <a href=""> Collection N°11</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="column _25">
    Project photoshoot
  </div>
  <div class="column _55">
    <canvas id="c"></canvas>


  <div id="top">
    <a id="close" href="">Reset tissue</a>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column _20">
    Red is a celebratory color. It commemorates a couple’s union. It symbolizes love, sensuality, and passion. That’s why it features prominently in auspicious occasions, such as weddings, festivals, and births. As red also signifies chastity, it is the color of choice for brides. 
  </div>
</div>



  
<footer>
  <div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    ©Copyright Angelo Barbattini
  </div>
  <div class="column">
   ECAL 2022
  </div>
</div>
</footer style="position: fixed;bottom: 0;">
<!--div id="new">
  Wobble some <a target="_blank" href="https://codepen.io/dissimulate/details/dJgMaO">jelly</a> <span class="bull">&bull;</span>
  Check out my <a target="_blank" href="https://www.instagram.com/abro_oks/">instagram!</a>
</div-->
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementById("close").onmousedown = function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  document.getElementById("info").style.display = "none";
  return false;
};

// settings

var physics_accuracy = 3,
  mouse_influence = 20,
  mouse_cut = 5,
  gravity = 1200,
  cloth_height = 30,
  cloth_width = 50,
  start_y = 20,
  spacing = 7,
  tear_distance = 60;

window.requestAnimFrame =
  window.requestAnimationFrame ||
  window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
  window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
  window.oRequestAnimationFrame ||
  window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
  function (callback) {
    window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
  };

var canvas,
  ctx,
  cloth,
  boundsx,
  boundsy,
  mouse = {
    down: false,
    button: 1,
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    px: 0,
    py: 0
  };

var Point = function (x, y) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.px = x;
  this.py = y;
  this.vx = 0;
  this.vy = 0;
  this.pin_x = null;
  this.pin_y = null;

  this.constraints = [];
};

Point.prototype.update = function (delta) {
  if (mouse.down) {
    var diff_x = this.x - mouse.x,
      diff_y = this.y - mouse.y,
      dist = Math.sqrt(diff_x * diff_x + diff_y * diff_y);

    if (mouse.button == 1) {
      if (dist < mouse_influence) {
        this.px = this.x - (mouse.x - mouse.px) * 1.8;
        this.py = this.y - (mouse.y - mouse.py) * 1.8;
      }
    } else if (dist < mouse_cut) this.constraints = [];
  }

  this.add_force(0, gravity);

  delta *= delta;
  nx = this.x + (this.x - this.px) * 0.99 + (this.vx / 2) * delta;
  ny = this.y + (this.y - this.py) * 0.99 + (this.vy / 2) * delta;

  this.px = this.x;
  this.py = this.y;

  this.x = nx;
  this.y = ny;

  this.vy = this.vx = 0;
};

Point.prototype.draw = function () {
  if (!this.constraints.length) return;

  var i = this.constraints.length;
  while (i--) this.constraints[i].draw();
};

Point.prototype.resolve_constraints = function () {
  if (this.pin_x != null && this.pin_y != null) {
    this.x = this.pin_x;
    this.y = this.pin_y;
    return;
  }

  var i = this.constraints.length;
  while (i--) this.constraints[i].resolve();

  this.x > boundsx
    ? (this.x = 2 * boundsx - this.x)
    : 1 > this.x && (this.x = 2 - this.x);
  this.y < 1
    ? (this.y = 2 - this.y)
    : this.y > boundsy && (this.y = 2 * boundsy - this.y);
};

Point.prototype.attach = function (point) {
  this.constraints.push(new Constraint(this, point));
};

Point.prototype.remove_constraint = function (constraint) {
  this.constraints.splice(this.constraints.indexOf(constraint), 1);
};

Point.prototype.add_force = function (x, y) {
  this.vx += x;
  this.vy += y;

  var round = 400;
  this.vx = ~~(this.vx * round) / round;
  this.vy = ~~(this.vy * round) / round;
};

Point.prototype.pin = function (pinx, piny) {
  this.pin_x = pinx;
  this.pin_y = piny;
};

var Constraint = function (p1, p2) {
  this.p1 = p1;
  this.p2 = p2;
  this.length = spacing;
};

Constraint.prototype.resolve = function () {
  var diff_x = this.p1.x - this.p2.x,
    diff_y = this.p1.y - this.p2.y,
    dist = Math.sqrt(diff_x * diff_x + diff_y * diff_y),
    diff = (this.length - dist) / dist;

  if (dist > tear_distance) this.p1.remove_constraint(this);

  var px = diff_x * diff * 0.5;
  var py = diff_y * diff * 0.5;

  this.p1.x += px;
  this.p1.y += py;
  this.p2.x -= px;
  this.p2.y -= py;
};

Constraint.prototype.draw = function () {
  ctx.moveTo(this.p1.x, this.p1.y);
  ctx.lineTo(this.p2.x, this.p2.y);
};

var Cloth = function () {
  this.points = [];

  var start_x = canvas.width / 2 - (cloth_width * spacing) / 2;

  for (var y = 0; y <= cloth_height; y++) {
    for (var x = 0; x <= cloth_width; x++) {
      var p = new Point(start_x + x * spacing, start_y + y * spacing);

      x != 0 && p.attach(this.points[this.points.length - 1]);
      y == 0 && p.pin(p.x, p.y);
      y != 0 && p.attach(this.points[x + (y - 1) * (cloth_width + 1)]);

      this.points.push(p);
    }
  }
};

Cloth.prototype.update = function () {
  var i = physics_accuracy;

  while (i--) {
    var p = this.points.length;
    while (p--) this.points[p].resolve_constraints();
  }

  i = this.points.length;
  while (i--) this.points[i].update(0.016);
};

Cloth.prototype.draw = function () {
  ctx.beginPath();

  var i = cloth.points.length;
  while (i--) cloth.points[i].draw();

  ctx.stroke();
};

function update() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  cloth.update();
  cloth.draw();

  requestAnimFrame(update);
}

function start() {
  canvas.onmousedown = function (e) {
    mouse.button = e.which;
    mouse.px = mouse.x;
    mouse.py = mouse.y;
    var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    (mouse.x = e.clientX - rect.left),
      (mouse.y = e.clientY - rect.top),
      (mouse.down = true);
    e.preventDefault();
  };

  canvas.onmouseup = function (e) {
    mouse.down = false;
    e.preventDefault();
  };

  canvas.onmousemove = function (e) {
    mouse.px = mouse.x;
    mouse.py = mouse.y;
    var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    (mouse.x = e.clientX - rect.left),
      (mouse.y = e.clientY - rect.top),
      e.preventDefault();
  };

  canvas.oncontextmenu = function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  };

  boundsx = canvas.width - 1;
  boundsy = canvas.height - 1;

  ctx.strokeStyle = "#888";

  cloth = new Cloth();

  update();
}

window.onload = function () {
  canvas = document.getElementById("c");
  ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

  canvas.width = 560;
  canvas.height = 350;

  start();
};

</script>
</body>
</html>```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Celmj.jpg
````

Comment: Please focus on just one problem per question and create a minimal reproducible example for us to run. Also please check your question, I am not able to see you image. Thanks.

Comment: here is the image in correct ratio : https://i.stack.imgur.com/Celmj.jpg

Comment: Here is what the website should look like, the blue arrow is the mouse on hover : https://imgur.com/MjlcA2K

Comment: There seem to be two main completely separate problems here - drawing the cloth and laying out the website. I suggest re-asking the first part only at this stage with a lot more explanation of what is to happen when the user uses the mouse and including just that part of the code that is supposed to create one piece of cloth. As you say, this is your main problem and it’s more complex than website layout. For example, I can’t at the moment see what the physics has to do with the cloth creation, hence the need for a fuller verbal explanation.

Comment: The cloth reacts and moves with wind according to mouse click and drag. it dosent get ripped with right click.

Comment: easier way to put it, ignore the website, how would it be possible to put an image on this https://plugindetector.com/cloth

Comment: OK, there may be a way to do this, but it's not entirely trivial as it requires taking small parts of the image and moving each one - it could be quite a CPU and/or GPU overhead. I will look into it and if I find a way will put it in an answer. In the meantime please could you edit your question to concentrate on this one problem (i.e. moving an image as though it were a piece of cloth) as I see it has already been marked for potential closure as not following SO requirements. Remove the other bits and cut down the code to show just the cloth moving stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The questioner is focusing on the problem of getting an actual image to look like material being moved with the wind.

The code presented to do this divides a canvas into small rectangular elements and moves each of those as required by the 'physics' given (value of gravity/wind for example).

The original just draws grid lines for each of these areas. What we need is for the equivalent rectangle in the original image to be copied to that point.

This snippet achieves this by adding a origx/y to the info kept about each point so that we know where to find the original rectangle.

It brings the image into an img element (it is important to wait until this is loaded before doing more with it) then copies it to an off-screen canvas that has the same dimensions as the one which will hold the material. This canvas is inspected when we need the 'mini image' to put at a given point.

WARNING: this code (even without the introduction of an image) is pretty processor intensive. On a farily powerful laptop with good GPU it was taking around 19% of CPU and not much less of GPU and the fan was whirring. This is even when there is no movement of the mouse. The code could do with a thorough look through, for example to stop the timer when user activity is completed, and perhaps putting the frame rate down (it's 60fps in the given code). I would not recommend it be put in a webpage and left there running - it will be a battery drainer.

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <!-- 
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    -->

  <script type="text/javascript" src=""></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="">

  <style type="text/css">
    body {}
    
    .wrapper {}
    
    * {
      margin: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      -webkit-user-select: none;
      -moz-user-select: none;
      -ms-user-select: none;
      -o-user-select: none;
      user-select: none;
    }
    
    body {
      background: #333;
    }
    
    canvas {
      background: #333;
      width: 100%;
      height: 376px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      display: block;
      border: solid red 2px;
    }
    
    #info {
      position: absolute;
      left: -1px;
      top: -1px;
      width: auto;
      max-width: 380px;
      height: auto;
      background: #f2f2f2;
      border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    }
    
    #top {
      background: #fff;
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
      position: relative;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
    }
    
    p {
      font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
      color: #666;
      text-align: justify;
      font-size: 16px;
      margin: 10px;
    }
    
    a {
      font-family: sans-serif;
      color: #444;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 20px;
    }
    
    #site {
      float: left;
      margin: 10px;
      color: #38a;
      border-bottom: 1px dashed #888;
    }
    
    #site:hover {
      color: #7af;
    }
    
    #close {
      float: right;
      margin: 10px;
    }
    
    #p {
      font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
      position: absolute;
      right: 10px;
      bottom: 10px;
      color: #adf;
      border: 1px dashed #555;
      padding: 4px 8px;
    }
  </style>
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Celmj.jpg" style="margin-top: -2000px; position: absolute;">
  <canvas width="1360" height="376" style="margin-top: -2000px; position: absolute;"></canvas>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    /*
    Copyright (c) 2013 lonely-pixel.com, Stuffit at codepen.io (http://codepen.io/stuffit)

    View this and others at http://lonely-pixel.com

    Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:

    The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
    */


    const mycanvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
    const mycontext = mycanvas.getContext('2d');

    // settings


    var physics_accuracy = 5,
      mouse_influence = 20,
      mouse_cut = 6,
      gravity = 900,
      cloth_height = 30,
      cloth_width = 50,
      start_y = 20,
      spacing = 7,
      tear_distance = 60;


    window.requestAnimFrame =
      window.requestAnimationFrame ||
      window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
      window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
      window.oRequestAnimationFrame ||
      window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
      function(callback) {
        window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
      };

    var canvas,
      ctx,
      cloth,
      boundsx,
      boundsy,
      mouse = {
        down: false,
        button: 1,
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        px: 0,
        py: 0
      };

    window.onload = function() {
      // ADDED TO BRING IN THE IMAGE
      mycontext.clearRect(0, 0, mycanvas.width, mycanvas.height);
      mycontext.drawImage(document.querySelector('img'), 0, 0, 1180, 376);


      canvas = document.getElementById('c');
      ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

      canvas.width = canvas.clientWidth;
      canvas.height = 376;

      canvas.onmousedown = function(e) {
        mouse.button = e.which;
        mouse.px = mouse.x;
        mouse.py = mouse.y;
        var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
        mouse.x = e.clientX - rect.left,
          mouse.y = e.clientY - rect.top,
          mouse.down = true;
        e.preventDefault();
      };

      canvas.onmouseup = function(e) {
        mouse.down = false;
        e.preventDefault();
      };

      canvas.onmousemove = function(e) {
        mouse.px = mouse.x;
        mouse.py = mouse.y;
        var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
        mouse.x = e.clientX - rect.left,
          mouse.y = e.clientY - rect.top,
          e.preventDefault();
      };

      canvas.oncontextmenu = function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
      };

      boundsx = canvas.width - 1;
      boundsy = canvas.height - 1;

      ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgba(222,222,222,0.6)';
      ctx.strokeStyle = 'magenta';
      cloth = new Cloth();
      update();
    };

    var Point = function(x, y) {

      this.x = x;
      this.y = y;
      this.px = x;
      this.py = y;
      this.vx = 0;
      this.vy = 0;
      this.pin_x = null;
      this.pin_y = null;
      this.constraints = [];
      //added - remember where this point was originally so we can get the right bit of the img
      this.origx = x;
      this.origy = y;
    };

    Point.prototype.update = function(delta) {

      if (mouse.down) {

        var diff_x = this.x - mouse.x,
          diff_y = this.y - mouse.y,
          dist = Math.sqrt(diff_x * diff_x + diff_y * diff_y);

        if (mouse.button == 1) {

          if (dist < mouse_influence) {
            this.px = this.x - (mouse.x - mouse.px) * 1.8;
            this.py = this.y - (mouse.y - mouse.py) * 1.8;
          }

        } else if (dist < mouse_cut) this.constraints = [];
      }

      this.add_force(0, gravity);

      delta *= delta;
      nx = this.x + ((this.x - this.px) * .99) + ((this.vx / 2) * delta);
      ny = this.y + ((this.y - this.py) * .99) + ((this.vy / 2) * delta);

      this.px = this.x;
      this.py = this.y;

      this.x = nx;
      this.y = ny;

      this.vy = this.vx = 0
    };

    Point.prototype.draw = function() {

      if (this.constraints.length <= 0) return;

      var i = this.constraints.length;
      while (i--) this.constraints[i].draw();
    };

    Point.prototype.resolve_constraints = function() {

      if (this.pin_x != null && this.pin_y != null) {

        this.x = this.pin_x;
        this.y = this.pin_y;
        return;
      }

      var i = this.constraints.length;
      while (i--) this.constraints[i].resolve();

      this.x > boundsx ? this.x = 2 * boundsx - this.x : 1 > this.x && (this.x = 2 - this.x);
      this.y < 1 ? this.y = 2 - this.y : this.y > boundsy && (this.y = 2 * boundsy - this.y);
    };

    Point.prototype.attach = function(point) {

      this.constraints.push(
        new Constraint(this, point)
      );
    };

    Point.prototype.remove_constraint = function(lnk) {

      var i = this.constraints.length;
      while (i--)
        if (this.constraints[i] == lnk) this.constraints.splice(i, 1);
    };

    Point.prototype.add_force = function(x, y) {

      this.vx += x;
      this.vy += y;
    };

    Point.prototype.pin = function(pinx, piny) {
      this.pin_x = pinx;
      this.pin_y = piny;
    };

    var Constraint = function(p1, p2) {

      this.p1 = p1;
      this.p2 = p2;
      this.length = spacing;
    };

    Constraint.prototype.resolve = function() {

      var diff_x = this.p1.x - this.p2.x,
        diff_y = this.p1.y - this.p2.y,
        dist = Math.sqrt(diff_x * diff_x + diff_y * diff_y),
        diff = (this.length - dist) / dist;

      if (dist > tear_distance) this.p1.remove_constraint(this);

      var px = diff_x * diff * 0.5;
      var py = diff_y * diff * 0.5;

      this.p1.x += px;
      this.p1.y += py;
      this.p2.x -= px;
      this.p2.y -= py;
    };
    let num = 0;
    Constraint.prototype.draw = function() {

      ctx.drawImage(mycanvas, this.p1.origx, this.p1.origy, spacing, spacing, this.p1.x, this.p1.y, spacing + 1, spacing + 1);
    };

    var Cloth = function() {

      this.points = [];

      var start_x = canvas.width / 2 - cloth_width * spacing / 2;

      for (var y = 0; y <= cloth_height; y++) {

        for (var x = 0; x <= cloth_width; x++) {

          var p = new Point(start_x + x * spacing, start_y + y * spacing);

          x != 0 && p.attach(this.points[this.points.length - 1]);
          y == 0 && p.pin(p.x, p.y);
          y != 0 && p.attach(this.points[x + (y - 1) * (cloth_width + 1)])

          this.points.push(p);
        }
      }
    };

    Cloth.prototype.update = function() {

      var i = physics_accuracy;

      while (i--) {
        var p = this.points.length;
        while (p--) this.points[p].resolve_constraints();
      }

      i = this.points.length;
      while (i--) this.points[i].update(.016);
    };

    Cloth.prototype.draw = function() {
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      ctx.beginPath();

      var i = cloth.points.length;
      while (i--) cloth.points[i].draw();

      ctx.stroke();
    };

    function update() {

      cloth.update();
      cloth.draw();

      requestAnimFrame(update);
    }
  </script>

</head>

<body>

  <canvas id="c" width="800" height="376"> </canvas>




</body>

</html>
```

Note: it is possible to 'tear' the material with a right click and this facility probably needs removing - unless you want users to ruin the look of the cloth :)